# Modify a tikz 3D image

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

This is the image I would like to modify
[image]

Here the modifications that I want:

- remove the box and maintein only the 3 main axis
- tilt along y-direction the 3D function inside
- make the function smoother
- add some bold lines belonging to the colored surface

Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, transform shape]

\begin{axis}[samples=40, xlabel=$l_3$, ylabel=$l_3$, zlabel=\empty,
axis lines=middle]
    \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
    \addplot3[surf, domain=0.2:5] {1/(x^2)+(1.7)^x+1.5*y};
    \addplot3[draw=black,line width=2pt, domain=0.6:5.4] (1,{x},{2*x});
    \addplot3[draw=black,line width=2pt, domain=1.1:5.9] (3,{x},{2*x});
    \addplot3[draw=red,line width=2pt, domain=0.9:5.7] (0.3,{x},{2*x});
    \addplot3[draw=red,line width=2pt, domain=0.85:5.7] (2.5,{x},{2*x});        
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I improve it?